# Creating instagram stories in premiere pro

Tags: premiere, android

I want to upload a short video to Instagram stories. What sequence/export settings should I use in premiere pro?

I tried a lot of video tutorials on this theme, but I end up in endless "processing" when I try to upload the story. Videos shot directly from phone have no issues. It might be android only issue...

To clarify, I open Instagram, click upload story button, I can select and play the video I exported from premiere pro, but it won't upload. Tried to lower bit rate so the result video file would fit under 1mb. Tried different resolutions and aspect ratios...

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S6